# Excel VBA: Insert cell in a table from searching another table

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

It's been years since I last had to code anything, but now I seem to need it again.

To simplify, I have number 7 in column A, and I need to input another number in column B depending on what number 7 relates to in another table in another sheet.

So in Sheet2 another table has numbers ranging from 1 to 10 in column A, and according numbers in column B. I then need it to search for number 7 in column A of sheet2 and give me the number in column B, and place it in column B in the first sheet.

I have tried a For loop inside a For loop, based on another code I found somewhere, but it's been so long ago I would need to spend hours rereading and trying to get near a solution. Maybe this is an easy thing for advanced coders?
Anyways, thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: no need of VBA: you could use LookUp() formula in Sheet1 column B cells that looks into Sheet2 column A cells and returns adjacent cell value

Comment: I didn't knew it could be this easy! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you referring to my comment or my answer?

Comment: The comment, there wasn't any need at all for vba. Though I am grateful for all other answers!

Answer (score 1):

couldn't you ever help without VBA then you can use this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, f As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sht1").Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--Change "Sht1" to your actual sheet1 name
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sht2").Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--Change "Sht2" to your actual sheet2 name
    For Each cell In rng1
        Set f = rng2.Find(what:=cell.Value2, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=xlNo)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then cell.Offset(, 1) = f.Offset(, 1)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways of doing searching over two tables.

```
Sub LoopValues()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsSearch As Worksheet
    Dim sourceLastRow As Long, searchLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set wsSource = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set wsSearch = Worksheets("Sheet4")

    With wsSource
        sourceLastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        searchLastRow = wsSearch.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To sourceLastRow

            For j = 2 To sourceLastRow

                If .Cells(i, 1).Value = wsSearch.Cells(j, 1).Value Then .Cells(i, 2).Value = wsSearch.Cells(j, 2).Value

            Next

        Next

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Sub FindValuesLoop()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsSearch As Worksheet
    Dim sourceLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim SearchRange As Range, rFound As Range


    Set wsSource = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set wsSearch = Worksheets("Sheet4")

    With wsSource
        sourceLastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set SearchRange = wsSearch.Range(wsSearch.Range("A1"), wsSearch.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        For i = 2 To sourceLastRow

            Set rFound = SearchRange.Find(What:=.Cells(i, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then .Cells(i, 2).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value

        Next

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```